# SSD, MBR, GPT and Linux (choices)

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, arch-linux, mbr, gpt

I'm getting a new computer with a 120GB SSD and a 500GB HDD @ 5400rpm, I will install Arch Linux on it and maybe Windows at some point. My indecision starts with the following issues:

I though about installing Linux `/boot` (512mb) `/` (root 60GB) and `/home` (remaning+2nd HDD). And the trouble starts here, how do I "divide" the `/home` partition in an SSD and an HDD? Should I do it this way or would I be better of with 120GB root partition (rather useless I think) and 500GB `/home` or is there a good way to do this. Should I choose GPT or MBR? GPT for SSD or for the HDD? Or for both?

What advantages would I get with GPT? And with MBR?

Sorry if it looks like I haven't looked up an answer before posting but I have but I still can't see it clear as to what to do.

Thank you.

PD: The computer comes with no OS pre-installed so I don't have to worry about Secure Boot things (those new problems encountered in Win8).

Comment: Other than the advantage of being able to create more than 4 'primary' partitions (GPT makes no distinction), I don't see any advantage of GPT with such small drives.

Comment: @Karan so I should stick with MBR in your opinion? What about the `/home` partition thing?

Comment: Well GPT is slightly more resilient than MBR due to redundancy of data structures on disk, and perhaps if you want to migrate to a bigger Advanced Format drive later and clone your OS then GPT might be the way to go. Regarding spanning the /home partition across disks, I'll leave that to a Linux expert to answer but I doubt its possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the home splitting question:

My suggestion is to just put the /home partition completely on the 500GB drive, and then if you REALLY need the SSD space, symlink something out of your home drive onto the SSD.